# Activity has been destroyed , is so weird

Tags: android

i have one and only one activity

there is no nested fragment and none of the similar questions apply to my situation , just a simple frame layout that i replace multiple fragments inside it , no more

the fragment replacement is trivial fragment transaction with no special code inside it

there is button and when i press that , the fragments are been created and replaced to the frame layout and added to back stack

the weirdo thing is that is see my activity in front of me sound and clear , it is right in front of me , and the fragment part of it is a small section of the view middle of the activity layout , but when i try to replace new fragments , some times i get the Activity has been destroyed illegal state exception

i have set break points in my code and i have digged into the FragmentManager.java source code and have found the source of exception

the weird thing is despite the activity is alive , but the mDestroyed field of it is set to true and also mDestroyed inside of Fragment manager has been set to true and mHost is set to null

sorry for the long description

but i`m totally confused that even though the activity is alive this exception is being fired and when catch the exception with the empty body , the activity continues its life and every other thing works perfect on activity .

help me here guys

this is where the exception happens inside Fragment manager :

```
 public void enqueueAction(OpGenerator action, boolean allowStateLoss) {
    if (!allowStateLoss) {
        checkStateLoss();
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mDestroyed || mHost == null) {
            if (allowStateLoss) {
                // This FragmentManager isn't attached, so drop the entire transaction.
                return;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity has been destroyed");
        }
        if (mPendingActions == null) {
            mPendingActions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        mPendingActions.add(action);
        scheduleCommit();
    }
}
```

this is my code , very simple

```
  val transaction = baseActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(getMessageAnimatorRes()[0],getMessageAnimatorRes()[1],getMessageAnimatorRes()[2],getMessageAnimatorRes()[3])
    transaction.addToBackStack("")
    transaction.replace(R.id.container,login.messagePage.Fragment.create(message,id,enableShadow,hideOKButton))
    transaction.commit()
```

log:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1351)
     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
      at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
      at com.eni.enim4s.TranslucentActivity$1.run(TranslucentActivity.java:70)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Put the code bro

Comment: Post your code, with crash logs .Story won't help .

Comment: @ADM  the reason i did not share my source code was the base class complexities you see and i didnt want you misleaded

Comment: @diegoveloper the reason i did not share my source code was the base class complexities you see and i didnt want you misleaded

Comment: be specific and post your error log too

Comment: please put your code completely to know

Answer (score 0):

after months of search , i just figured that it was because i had used an event bus system widely in my app.

and when the activities and fragments were started , they were subscribed for some events in the app.

for example one of my activities had subscribed for PLEASE_REPLACE_FRAGMENT event and when i went back and forth to that activity , the subscriptions were duplicated , but the previous ones were orphan and the activity inside them were finishing and destroyed

so the exception was odd to me.because when i traced the problem , i only see the lines that were supposed to run and i didnt recognized that those lines are being called twice .

so my advice is control the use of event dispatching and remember to clean up all subscriptions in onStop and subscribe again in onStart